# Full-width multi-column float with wrapped image

Tags: floats, multicolumn, wrapfigure

In a wide-margin book, I want to produce two-column biographical notes with a wrapped image, fixed at the bottom of pages (just as I can fix a float's position). How do I do that?

I have tried with the following snippet:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[left=.7in, bottom=1in, right=2.8in, marginparwidth=2.1in, marginparsep=.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullwidth}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10]

% \begin{fullwidth}[outermargin=-5cm,width=\linewidth+5cm]
\begin{multicols}{2}\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{100pt}\includegraphics[width=100pt]{newton.jpg}\end{wrapfigure} \footnotesize \noindent \textbf{Issac Newton} (1643\textendash1727) was a British physicist and mathematician. He is remembered as one of the greatest scientists of all time.

In his book \emph{Philosophi\ae Naturalis Principia Mathematica} (known as \emph{Principia} in short), published in 1687, he formulated mechanics and the law of gravitation, which brought a revolution in Physics and Astronomy. Before him Kepler had observed the motions of the planets of the solar system. But their explanation was unknown until then.

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[2]\end{multicols}
% \end{fullwidth}

\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

So far the snippet about produced the following two outputs and none of them are desired.

| Correct image wrapping. Not full-width. Not fixed at bottom | Full-width. Incorrect image location. Not fixed at bottom |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 1):

I have made some progress (nearly achieved what I wanted in fact). Using the `tcolorbox` (which supports both floating and wrapfigure) did the tick.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[left=.7in, bottom=1in, right=2.8in, marginparwidth=2.1in, marginparsep=.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullwidth}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10]

\begin{tcolorbox}[float*=!btp, width=\linewidth+5cm, boxrule=0pt, bottomrule=1pt, arc=0pt]
    \begin{multicols*}{2}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{100pt}\includegraphics[width=100pt]{newton.jpg}\end{wrapfigure} \footnotesize \textbf{Issac Newton} (1643\textendash1727) was a British physicist and mathematician. He is remembered as one of the greatest scientists of all time.
        
        In his book \emph{Philosophi\ae Naturalis Principia Mathematica} (known as \emph{Principia} in short), published in 1687, he formulated mechanics and the law of gravitation, which brought a revolution in Physics and Astronomy. Before him Kepler had observed the motions of the planets of the solar system. But their explanation was unknown until then.
        
        \lipsum[2]
        
        \lipsum[2]
        
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{multicols*}
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

Here follows what it produces. The output is exactly what I wanted except that the box always settles at the top of the page though I set bottom as the priority in the float properties (`!btp`).

[image]

Comment: You can accept own answer (and by this inform other members of site, that your problem is solved).